# Multiple Azure Functions with AzureWebJobStorage App Setting, Same KeyVault?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have two Azure Functions sharing a single KeyVault. Both Functions use KeyVault *references* in `local.settings.json` rather than plaintext secrets. Each function uses a **different** internal Azure Storage account (`AzureWebJobStorage`).

- How do I reference two different `AzureWebJobStorage` app settings using one KeyVault?
- Is there a way to change one of the settings to `AzureWebJobStorage1` or the like?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using Azure Key Vault references with Azure Functions does not support to work on local. for more details, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956664/can-azure-key-vault-be-used-with-functions-to-store-the-connection-string-for-qu).

The following answers are based on the functions on the Azure Portal

> How do I reference two different AzureWebJobStorage app settings using one KeyVault?

You need to add the storage `connect string` you need to the `key vault` on the Azure portal, and it will generate the corresponding `Secret Identifier`.

[image]

[image]

You can generate references that conform to the following syntax:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

Then add these two references to the app setting

[image]

> Is there a way to change one of the settings to AzureWebJobStorage1 or the like?

Of course, if you configure the key vault reference in the `app setting`, you can define your variable name as `AzureWebJobStorage1`.

[image]

Take the `blob trigger function` as an example, you can use `AzureWebJobStorage1` in the `function.json` file to get the storage connection.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm speaking about the INTERNAL Storage Used by the Function NOT the trigger. The INTERNAL storage has a default name of `AzureWebJobsStorage`. If I have two Functions sharing the same KeyVault, I can't have the same secret name. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I was being silly. It doesn't matter what the Key Vault secret is named. The `AzureWebJobsStorage` name stays the same in each function, but can be called anything in Key Vault.